# Protractor - Select from Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a [Bootstrap single-button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single) and I would like to click on one of the options appearing in the dropdown using Protractor. How do I accomplish this?

```
               <div class="btn-group" ng-if="!persist.edit" dropdown>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default"
                            dropdown-toggle>
                        <span translate="GENERAL.ACTIONS"></span>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                        <!-- Check In -->
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a ng-click="checkIn()"
                               role="menuitem"
                               tabindex="-1"
                               translate="ITEMS.LIST.BUTTON_CHECK_ITEM_IN">
                            </a>
                        </li>


                        <!-- Check Out -->
                        <li role="presentation"">
                            <a ng-click="checkOut()"
                               role="menuitem"
                               tabindex="-1"
                               translate="ITEMS.LIST.BUTTON_CHECK_ITEM_OUT"
                               translate-value-length="1">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I tried this (dropdown is called, but click fails):

```
it('Should click Actions button and show dropdown', function(){
    element(by.buttonText("Actions")).click(); 
    browser.sleep(1000);
});
it('Should click the Check Item Out dropdown option and change status to checked out', function(){
    element(by.css('[value="ITEMS.LIST.BUTTON_CHECK_ITEM_OUT"]')).click();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, click the "dropdown toggle" button to open up the dropdown. Then, select an option:

```
var dropDown = element(by.css("div[dropdown]"));
dropDown.element(by.css("button[dropdown-toggle]")).click(); 
dropDown.element(by.css("a[ng-click*=checkIn]")).click();  // Check In
```

Working code:

```
    element(by.buttonText("Actions")).click(); 
    element(by.css('[ng-click="]checkIn()"]')).click();  // Check In
```

Comment: Looks like it's not hitting the "checkIn" part (select from another anchor element on the page). I don't really understand the syntax, you are chaining, right? "Select anchor with ng-click class = "checkIn". Why the *?

Comment: @VSO okay, updated, made it context-specific, specific to the dropdown. the `*=` basically means "contains".

Comment: I added an edit of what I attempted at the end of the post (I will delete after), but it's throwing an error. Note, I have about 10 dropdowns on the page, hence the var dropDown change. I know it selects the right dropdown with the way I did it. I assume it doesn't mess with your code, but let me know if it does.

Comment: Let me ask you a theoretical question again - after I click on the dropdown, should I be able to select the element by whatever, and then click on them, WITHOUT going through the parent element, theoretically? Or I HAVE to go through the parent? Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: @VSO sure, you are not required to "go through a parent element". Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution to select from Bootstrap Dropdown is to click by buttonText and then by linkText:

```
element(by.buttonText('your button')).click();
element(by.linkText('your selection')).click();
```